# What are the non-totient numbers from 300-500?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

http://oeis.org/search?q=14%2C26%2C34%2C38%2C50%2C62%2C68%2C74%2C76%2C86%2C90%2C94%2C98%2C114%2C118%2C122%2C124%2C134%2C142%2C146%2C152%2C154&language=english&go=Search
Above 
Gives the numbers up to 314. I was looking for up to 500. I can't find a generator for non-totient numbers in the range 300-500.

Comment: At the risk of being a little blunt, have you tried clicking some of the links on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{14,26,34,38,50,62,68,74,76,86,90,94,98,114,118,122,124,134,142,146,152,154,158,170,174,182,186,188,194,202,206,214,218,230,234,236,242,244,246,248,254,258,266,274,278,284,286,290,298,302,304,308,314,318,322,326,334,338,340,350,354,362,364,370,374,376,386,390,394,398,402,404,406,410,412,414,422,426,428,434,436,446,450,454,458,470,472,474,482,484,488,494,496,510,514,516,518,526,530,532,534,538,542,548,550,554,558,566,572,574,578,582,590,594,596,\ldots\}$

I used Mathematica code from the OP link

```
> searchMax = 600; phiAnsYldList = Table[0, {searchMax}]; Do[  phiAns =
> EulerPhi[m];   If[phiAns <= searchMax, phiAnsYldList[[phiAns]]++], {m,
> 1,    searchMax^2}]; Select[Range[searchMax],   EvenQ[#] &&
> (phiAnsYldList[[#]] == 0) &]
```